# java webapp module support

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing sample  webapp(servlet+html) and deploy on Tomcat. I am using Java 11 and tomcat-9. I don't see in Tomcat documentation on support for Java 9 modules.
Does Tomcat support Java 9 modules? or any workaround?

Comment: What have you tried, what do you see, what do you expect? Please see [ask] - as it is, your question is just asking for documentation, which is off topic (see [help/on-topic]). What's the problem you're trying to solve and on which step are you failing to solve it? Tomcat is loading a webapp, and is agnostic to however that webapp continues to find its classes. By default it loads classes according to the implemented servlet spec, e.g. from WEB-INF/lib, and doesn't do dynamic reloading. But you're free to extend the classloading mechanism

Comment: I am able to deploy the web app without using modules. I created jar file using module- module-info.java . I put this jar file inside web-inf/lib. In the servlet, i try to access  class in jar file using module. I created module-info.java in package where servlet resides. I get 'NoClassDefError"

Comment: Please add the error and complete stack trace to the question (not as a comment). Tomcat does not care about modules, but the JVM does.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: vendor.alloc.TicketReceiver
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
 sample.data.NameVerifier.doGet(NameVerifier.java:33)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: The class is in jar file which is present in web-inf/lib and i am accessing it through module